# Swift 5: Why swift 5 update ask to forcibly unwrap the label.font?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, swift5

The following code is throwing a warning for me after project is upgraded to Swift 5. Why is that? Can anyone tell me? why did they make it optional?

```
let attributes:[NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.userBioTextLabel.font]
```

> - Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'UIFont?' to 'Any'    does not unwrap optionally
>
>   - Provide a default value to avoid this
>   - warning Force-unwrap the value to avoid this warning
>   - Explicitly cast     to 'Any' with 'as Any' to silence this warning

Comment: What is `self.userBioTextLabel`? Is it an IBOutlet? If so, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422914/why-are-iboutlets-optionals-after-swift-5-migration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are IBOutlets optionals after swift 5 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422914/why-are-iboutlets-optionals-after-swift-5-migration)

Comment: @IBOutlet weak var userBioTextLabel: UILabel!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of your `userBioTextLabel` , Did you declare it as optional? If so you can force unwrap it , In the outlet declaration line or where you defined it first in your code to fix the warning